# Sentry with log4j2.properties

Tags: java, maven, log4j2, sentry

I'm trying to integrate Sentry in my Maven project that already uses log4j2.properties as log4j2 configuration file.

The [official documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/log4j2/) has just log4j2.xml as configuration example.

What is the way to configure the same example with log4j2.properties?

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem.

Here is my log4j2.properties

```
appenders = console,Sentry
 
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = ${env:log4j.csl.pattern:-info}

appender.Sentry=io.sentry.log4j.SentryAppender
appender.Sentry.name=Sentry
appender.Sentry.type=Sentry

 
rootLogger.level = ${env:log4j.root.loglevel:-info}
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT


loggers=csl,sentry
logger.csl.name = io.sirnino
logger.csl.level = ${env:log4j.csl.loglevel:-debug}
logger.csl.additivity = false
logger.csl.appenderRefs = stdout
logger.csl.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.sentry.name = sentry
logger.sentry.level = WARN
logger.sentry.appenderRefs = Sentry
```

The app starts properly but, in a nutshell, seems to ignore the Sentry logger. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In my case with log4j 2.17, I needed to add `packages = io.sentry.log4j2` to my `log4j2.properties` file.

Full file:

```
status = error
dest = err
name = MyName
packages = io.sentry.log4j2

monitorInterval = 5

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = LogToConsole
appender.console.layout.type = JsonLayout
appender.console.layout.compact = true
appender.console.layout.eventEol = true
appender.console.layout.properties = true

appender.sentry.name = Sentry
appender.sentry.type = Sentry
appender.sentry.dsn = https://key@my.domain.com

rootLogger.level = ${env:LOG_LEVEL:-debug}
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = LogToConsole
rootLogger.appenderRef.sentry.ref = Sentry
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution for integrating sentry with log4j2.properties worked for me perfectly along with stdout logging.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, sentry
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.sentry=io.sentry.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.sentry.Threshold=error
```

For this, I had to add log4j 1.x version of sentry to my pom.xml

Comment: Please could you also paste the code that you added in the pom ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work also with `log4j2.properties`. Have you tried and it failed?
Maybe the docs should explicitly state that it's supported.

If it doesn't work, you can raise an issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues

Comment: Ok, but what are the key-values to insert in the log4j2.properties?